# Stop images produced by pymc.Matplot.plot being saved

Tags: python, pymc

I recently started experimenting with pymc and only just realised that the images being produced by pymc.Matplot.plot, which I use to diagnose whether the MCMC has performed well, are being saved to disk. This results in images appearing wherever I am running my scripts from, and it is time consuming to clear them up. Is there a way to stop figures being saved to disk? I can't see anything clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to plot them without being saved to disk. I would recommend only plotting a few diagnostic parameters, and specifying `plot=False` for the others. That would at least cut down on the volume of plots being generated. There probably should be a `saveplot` argument, however, I agree.